# i try to change all the black color codes into white color codes

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I generated a TWBSColor code and i want to change all black color codes with white or other color at a certain time(i use a js code to look for the actual hour). i.e. if it's 12 PM all black codes change to white by searching the black codes and replace them with the white code color.

```
   <script>var thehours = new Date().getHours();
        if (thehours >= 8 && thehours < 20) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.getElementById("liniasexy").background='linear- 
gradient(to right, black, #f07f00)';
        } else if (thehours >= 20 && thehours < 8) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";

        }
    </script>
```

i use this to change the background color.

Comment: Go ahead and show us some code! ;)

Comment: Good! Now - what is the problem with your code?

Comment: i want to add a line of code that changes all the black color codes into white codes.

Comment: If you just want to change the foreground color of things that inherit their color from the document.body.style, you just have to set the document.body.style.color property. If you need more than that, you could try looking into using the css filter invert function. If that doesn't work for you, you may have to do some more complicated modifications to the stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

A [DOM Element object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) does not contain a property called `background`, you should set the value on the `style` property of that object, like so:

```
document.getElementById("liniasexy").style.background='linear-gradient(to right, black, #f07f00)';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `class` property to all elements you want to toggle background and use [document.querySelectorAll('selectors')](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like this:

```
var toggleBackgroundItems = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle_bg");
toggleBackgroundItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.backgroundColor = 'white';
});
```

**Working example**:

```js
function toggleBg() {
  var toggleBackgroundItems = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle_bg");
  toggleBackgroundItems.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.style.backgroundColor === 'black') {
      item.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      item.style.color = 'black';
    } else {   
      item.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      item.style.color = 'white';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#container {
  display:flex
}

#container span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.blue {
 background-color: blue;
}

.green {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleBg()">Toggle background color</button>
<br><br>
<p class="toggle_bg">A paragraph</p>
<div id="container">
  <span class="blue">Blue</span>
  <span class="toggle_bg">Toggle</span>
  <span class="green">Green</span>
  <span class="toggle_bg">Toggle</span>
  <span class="toggle_bg">Toggle</span>
  <span class="green">Green</span>
  <span class="blue">Blue</span>
</div>
```